# Django 404.html causes 500

Tags: django

I wrote a `404.html` page in the root template directory, along with the `500.html` page. But when I call a nonsensical URL, it shows the `500.html` page, meaning the server is erroring somewhere when loading the `404.html` page. With some debugging, I saw that the template loader had found and loaded my 404 page, but was erroring when rendering it: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'kwargs'`. I still get an error if I reduce the `404.html` page to `<html>Hello World.</html>`, so the problem isn't in the template syntax. What's happening?

Notes: The other pages still serve, without static files, as I've read in other Stack Overflow posts. My settings file has `DEBUG = False` and `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`.

Comment: Response middleware is still executed after the error handler has run. If that causes an exception, you'll get a 500. If that basic template still causes an error you either have to reload your server, or your middleware is at fault.

Comment: can you paste the stack trace ?

Comment: @knbk actual pages still work though... karthikr- is there an easy way to do that? I just found the trouble spot and did a try/catch to print the exception

Comment: And what would that prove? I bet your response middleware tries to use `request.resolver_match.kwargs` without checking `request.resolver_match`.

Comment: @knbk I have only default Django middleware, which shouldn't error on a resolver_match, right? ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

Comment: Ok, that's probably not it, that would've been noticed and fixed by now. Are you using a custom error handler? And are you absolutely sure that it doesn't match any patterns?

Comment: ohh @knbk you're right. Just did a stack traceback and the error occured in a custom context processor. Thanks!